# What does memset(foo->a+foo->b, 0, 10) mean?

Tags: c, pointers

I have this piece of code in one library I'm using and I'm wondering what it does, since I'm having problems with memory I suppose this is the reason.

So the piece of code is following:

```
    int new_size = foo->a_size + 10;
    foo->a = realloc(foo->a, new_size*sizeof(struct items));
    memset(foo->a+foo->a_size, 0, 10);
```

`foo->a` is type `struct items*` and `foo->a_size` is type `int`.

First lines reallocate 10 blocks of new memory but now I'm wondering if `memset()` sets both `foo->a` and `foo->a_size` to 0 or should this set blocks from 11-20 to 0 in `foo->a`?
I have tried to run this code block on its own and receive only `Segmentation fault`

**EDIT:**

Question was that does the `memset()` set both `foo->a` and `foo->a_size` to 0 or does it set blocks from offset `foo->a_size` to `0` in `foo->a`. The latter assumption was correct but I need to also fix the `memset()` so the last argument is `10 * sizeof(struct items)`. I also edited variable names from `foo->b` to `foo->a_size`.

Comment: Regardless of the result, `foo->a = realloc(foo->a,....` is a pretty bad habit / coding style. Imagine, realloc fails..........

Comment: 'foo->a'  is the pointer to the allocated memory, 'foo->b' is an offset into it.   Could be written clearer and safer!

Comment: Are they really called 'a' and 'b' or do they have meaningful names?

Comment: There should be a line that updates `foo->b` as well?

Comment: @slim They have meaningful names, but I thought that it's okay to use a and b since the real names were longer and they don't give any extra information.

Comment: They probably do have extra information. I would expect them to be called something like `itemsArray` and `itemsArrayLength` -- and that kind of makes the question answer itself.

Comment: We really should know how (at least) `a` is defined. Without known this, all  is guessing.

Comment: I edited the question. The names was like that, and now as you say, it's a lot clearer. Hopefully this question helps someone else too and not just me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are initializing `10` Bytes in `foo->a`(`pointer`) with `foo->b`(`int`) offset. In the other words you just initialized appended memory.

**Example:**

Lets assume `foo->a` is `int*` and is pointing to 5 `int`s continuous block.

```
+---+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

You need 10 `int`s, so you will `realloc` that block to size `10` * `sizeof(int)` Bytes, but appended `5` * `sizeof(int)` Bytes are uninitialized.

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | ? | ? | ? | ? | ? |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

So by doing

```
memset(pointerToFirstByte + Offset, 0, 5 * sizeof(int));
```

You will init these appended bytes to `0`.

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
                      ^---^---^---^---^------ Initialized to 0
```

Comment: `foo_b` would be the offset; `foo->a+foo->b` would be a pointer

Answer (score 4):

The line in question sets 10 bytes starting with an offset by `foo->b` from `foo->a` to 0. The offset is in steps the size of the structure items. We don't have enough information to further explain this, but my speculation is that foo->a is a pointer to a dynamically allocated array of the structure and here we are setting the fields of part of it(possibly one element?) to 0.

Comment: It's not the byte offset of `foo->b`. It's an offset of `foo->b * sizeof(struct items)` because of pointer arithmetics, isn't it? So it will set 10 bytes from that address on.

Comment: It is offset of foo->a, not of foo->b, but indeed you are right it will be offset in size of the struct not in bytes

Comment: So does it change structs 11-20 or structs 21-30?

Comment: @J.Rautava for what values of `foo->b` and what is the size of `struct items`?

Comment: @AndreKampling I have edited my answer that you for your correction

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev: And I've upvoted this because it's right now.

Comment: @AndreKampling Filips answer made it clearer to me and it was the thing I was asking but couldn't put it out clear enough.

Comment: @J.Rautava then the right thing to do is accept that answer and possibly upvote it. Also try to edit your question to better explain what you are trying to ask for.

Answer (score 3):

So these 2 lines increase `foo->a` by 10 lots of whatever `struct items` is.

```
int new_size = foo->b + 10;
foo->a = realloc(foo->a, new_size*sizeof(struct items));
```

This sets 10 bytes of memory of `foo->a` offset by `foo->b * sizeof(struct items)` to 0

```
memset(foo->a+foo->b, 0, 10);
```

which isn't probably enough as it's unlikely `struct items` is just 1 byte in size. What you should be doing is clearly 10 lots of `struct items` like this.

```
memset(foo->a+foo->b, 0, 10*sizeof(struct items));
```

Answer (score 1):

The `memset` in the code fragment initializes 10 bytes in the newly allocated part of `foo->a` to `0`. There are multiple problems in this code:

- You do not test for `realloc()` failure.
- You overwrite `foo->a` with the return value from `realloc()`. If `realloc()` fails, the block previouly pointed to by `foo->a` is still allocated but potentially unreachable, a memory leak.
- The space set to `0` is most probably too small.
- Initializing to all bits 0 might not be appropriate for the structure `items`.
- You do not update `foo->size`.

Here is an improved version:

```
size_t new_size = foo->a_size + 10;
struct items *newp = realloc(foo->a, new_size * sizeof(*foo->a));
if (newp == NULL) {
    // handle the error
} else {
    memset(newp + foo->a_size, 0, (new_size - foo->a_size) * sizeof(*foo->a));
    foo->a = newp;
    foo->a_size = new_size;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
memset(foo->a+foo->b, 0, 10);
```

This line sets the 10 Bytes of **Foo->a** to **0**. 
**foo->a + foo->b** is a offset value in it.